# string.slice() retorna string vazia

Tags: javascript, string, slice

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de juntar palavras, e pensei em usar o `.slice()`. Mas retorna uma string vazia. Eu já pesquisei mas ninguém explicou isso direito. Eu tenho dois inputs de texto, e quero fazer com que o primeiro perca a segunda metade e o segundo perca a primeira metade. Esse é o código que retorna uma string vazia:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="name1"><input type="text" id="name2"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Juntar" onclick="juntar()"><br>
  <script>
    var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
    var name2 = document.getElementById('name2').value;

    function juntar() {
      var name1slice = `${name1.slice(0, name1.length / 2)}`
      var name2slice = `${name2.slice(name2.length / 2, name2.length)}`
      var slice12 = `${name1slice}${name2slice}`
      alert(`${slice12}`)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Só um detalhe, não precisa usar template string nesses casos, poderia fazer apenas `var name1slice = name1.slice(0, name1.length / 2)` e `alert(slice12)`, por exemplo. Mesmo para concatenar, poderia ser `slice12 = name1slice + name2slice`

Comment: eu não sabia disso, pensei que se eu fizesse ```slice12 = name1slice + name2slice``` o retorno seria NaN

Comment: Como `name1slice` e `name2slice` são strings (pois `slice` retorna uma string), o operador `+` concatena. `NaN` aparece quando vc tenta fazer operações matemáticas com strings que não representam números, etc. Mas nesse caso vc está manipulando somente strings, então pode concatenar sem problema

Comment: ok obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguinte, o que está acontecendo, é que o seu script executa quando o DOM é gerado, logo, os valores dos campos estão vazios. Pra resolver o seu problema de ter a string retornando vazia, basta declarar as variáveis dentro da função, assim os valores já existirão.

Seu script ficaria assim:

```
 <script>
        function juntar() {
            var name1slice = `${name1.slice(0, name1.length / 2)}`
            var name2slice = `${name2.slice(name2.length / 2, name2.length)}`
            var slice12 = `${name1slice}${name2slice}`
            var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
            var name2 = document.getElementById('name2').value;
            alert(`${slice12}`)
        }
 </script>
```

Se o resultado ainda não for o esperado, o erro estará na lógica utilizada nos `slice()`